# up and down arrows javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'll explain what to do next , while here is html code =>

```
<fieldset>
         <legend>Get&nbsp;Data&nbsp;Ajax</legend>
         <form name="ajax" method="get" action="getData.php">
         <input type="text" name="getName" id="getName">
         </form>
         <div class="resBox" id="resBox"></div> <!-- this div is where results are placed-->
</fieldset>
```

I've written ajax script which is retrieving some info from mysql database onkeyup in input field and then I have done also how to collapse info down from this field. Here is the situation , can anyone explain how to do (when info already collapsed) that in up and down arrows could movement into info ? Please give an advice how to do that ?

In conclusion I am interested in how to handle javascript key events. please give some examples, thanks :)

I've tried like so but it is not working =>

```
var key;
if (window.event){
    key = e.keyCode;
} else {
    key = e.which;
}

if (key==13){ // enter for example 
    alert("something");
}
```

Comment: I got lost here - "can anyone explain how to do (when info already collapsed) that in up and down arrows could movement into info?"

Comment: in other words , when data has already been collapsed in marked place, how to movement cursor up and down with arrows , like this function has for example google youtube and etc

Comment: If this is not a learning exercise, you're probably better of with something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ instead of creating your own.

Comment: have done already , thanks anyways :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JS code should probably work in your context. See a working Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4VCK/).

```
el = document.body;
if (typeof el.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    el.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        doThis(evt.keyCode);
    }, false);
} else if (typeof el.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    el.attachEvent("onkeydown", function(evt) {
        doThis(evt.keyCode);
    });
}

function doThis(key) {
    switch (key) {
        case 13:
            alert('enter pressed');
            break;
        case 27:
            alert('esc pressed');
            break;
        case 38:
            alert('up pressed');
            break;
        case 40:
            alert('down pressed');
            break;
    }
}
```

First of all consider reading this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690904/javascript-bind-keyup-down-event). 
And you can read [this MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets) too.