# Go button of iPhone for a page submit for login page using c#

Tags: c#

I have an asp.net application for mobile devices using c#. When I run my log in page in a browser, pressing an enter key brings me to the next page.

But when I press the "Go" button in an iPhone, nothing happens. Is there specific code that I have to write for mobile devices?

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does "clicking" the submit button explicitly work on iOS?

Comment: Yes. Just the "Go" button does not submit the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to be done via javascript using the key bind. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690922/1435499

If you are not dealing with webforms then javascript is way to go, it will also help when the users press enter using the browsers.

Comment: Actually pressing enter in browsers work. Just "go" button in ios device does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the

```
<input type = "button"> to <input type = "submit"> and 
margin-left: -1000px. It worked.
```

Comment: Arpita, that's good. Every form should have a submit button to trigger the http method of the form :)